# Oracle "NOT IN" query

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to figure out the SQL to return a list of users when something is not in another table.  I realize there are a few ways to accomplish this but what is the preferred method? What I have below is my guess which doesn't work as needed.

```
SELECT
  n.nid,
  n.title,
  u.uid,
  u.mail
FROM node n
JOIN field_data_field_status fs            ON n.nid=fs.entity_id
JOIN flagging f                            ON n.nid=f.entity_id
JOIN users u                               ON f.uid=u.uid
JOIN profile p                             ON p.uid=u.uid
WHERE n.nid='891'
  AND n.type='tournament'
  AND fs.field_data_field_status_value='In_progress'
  AND p.pid NOT IN (select entity_id FROM field_data_field_selected_players)";
```

In this example the `entity_id` from `field_data_field_selected_players` would equal `p.pid`.

So I essentially want a list of users who don't have a `p.pid` found in `entity_id` of `field_data_field_selected_players`.

Comment: `which doesn't work as needed` this tells nothing useful. Elaborate on that.

Comment: It would be helpful for you to explain why your query doesn't work, what are the expected results and what did you get, also some test data and your table structures would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is ommiting *profiles* that don't have an entry in field_data_field_selected_players, where you say you want it to be *users* to be ommited. So it's essentially users who don't have a profile with such an entry. The NOT IN clause must hence look for *users*.

```
SELECT
  n.nid,
  n.title,
  u.uid,
  u.mail
FROM node n
JOIN field_data_field_status fs            ON n.nid=fs.entity_id
JOIN flagging f                            ON n.nid=f.entity_id
JOIN users u                               ON f.uid=u.uid
WHERE n.nid='891'
  AND n.type='tournament'
  AND fs.field_data_field_status_value='In_progress'
  AND u.uid NOT IN
  (
    select p.uid
    from profile p
    where p.pid IN (select entity_id FROM field_data_field_selected_players)
  );
```

The same can be done with EXISTS / NOT EXISTS of course. It's mainly a matter of personal preference which to choose. I often prefer IN / NOT IN for their simplicity.